# How does the Austrian School view land rents?

Tags: property, austrian, land

I have come across these publications:

[The Spatial Market Process. Advances in Austrian Economics Vol. 16.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234999169_The_Spatial_Market_Process)

> In “An Austrian Theory of Spatial Land,” Fred E. Foldvary addresses
> the disregard of spatial issues in basic Austrian economic theory as
> formulated by Carl Menger (1871) and elaborated upon by Ludwig von
> Mises (1940). Foldvary shows that Johann Heinrich von Thünen (1826)
> and Henry George (1879/1884), in particular, serve to fill these gaps
> in the classical Austrian theory of the market process.

[Henry George and the Austrian Economists](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1111/1536-7150.00135) (Oscar Johannsen, 2003)
This article states that Rothbard had a Lockean view of property in land:

> every man has the absolute right of property in his own self and in
> the previously unowned natural resources which he finds